# In c++, c why conditions inside for loop block and within for loop acts differently?

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-loops

A condition inside for loop and a same condition inside for loop block.
Why these 2 gives different output?

```
for (i=0;i <5;i++)
{
       printf("\n");
       for (j=0;j <5;j++)
             if (i!=j)
                  printf (" i= %d j= %d ",i,j);
 }


for (i=0;i <5;i++)
{
        printf("\n");
        for (j=0;j <5 &&i!=j;j++)
               printf (" i= %d j= %d ",i,j);
  }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They produce different outputs because the inner loops are, in no way, equivalent.

The test `i != j` does not affect the number of iterations on the inner loop in the first form - the number of iterations will always be `5`, and the `if (i != j) ...` will be executed on every loop iteration.

However, in the second lot of code, `i != j` is now part of the loop condition, so the loop will terminate after five iterations OR the first time it finds `i != j` is false (i.e. if `i == j`).

Consider what happens in the two lots of code if `i` is zero.

In the first lot of code, the inner loop always iterates five times, and output is produced for all the values of `j != i`.  For `i` equal to zero, this means four lines of output are produced (for `j` with each of values `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` but not for `0`).

In the second lot of code, with `i` equal to zero, `i != j` will be false on the first value of `j` (zero) so the inner loop body will never be executed - and the loop body will not be executed for subsequent values of `j`.  No output will be produced.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop in the first example checks that `i != j` with every iteration but still iterates over all values for `j` in the range 0, ..., 4.

The inner loop in the second example, however, stops execution as soon as its condition

```
j < 5 && i != j
```

is false. This inner loop does not always perform 5 iterations: if `i != j` is true for values of `j` less than `5`, then the loop exits early.